# Facebook profile - app page or business page

Tags: facebook

I'm launching a web and desktop application soon where users can modify their photos.
So should I set up a Facebook **app page** or a **business page** for it?

( http://www.facebook.com/apps || http://www.facebook.com/pages )

Are there any pros and cons?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Both. If it's an app it has to have an app page. You might as well publicise your business as well though. You can point to the other one from each page.